# Requesting and Gathering Names for (x) number of people?

Tags: perl, stdin

for a project in Science class, I'm making a game in Perl. This is my intro for the game,

```
# Solar Game
# Copyright (c)2013 Donovan Roudabush
# Protected by GPU

print "  _________      .__                   ________                       \n";
print " /   _____/ ____ |  | _____ _______   /  _____/_____    _____   ____  \n";
print " \_____  \ /  _ \|  | \__  \\_  __ \ /   \  ___\__  \  /     \_/ __ \ \n";
print " /        (  <_> )  |__/ __ \|  | \/ \    \_\  \/ __ \|  Y Y  \  ___/ \n";
print "/_______  /\____/|____(____  /__|     \______  (____  /__|_|  /\___  > \n";
print "        \/                 \/                \/     \/      \/     \/ \n";
print "Version 1.0 Beta\n\n";
print "Developed by Donovan Roudabush\n";
print "https://github.com/sharksfan98/solargame\n\n";
print "Press enter to start\n";
$ok = <STDIN>;
chomp $ok;
print "Enter the number of players\n";
$num = <STDIN>;
chomp $num;
```

Now, with the value **$num** (which stores the number of players), how to I print out the line below for (x) amount of players to collect their names?

```
print "Please enter your name\n";
$name1 = <STDIN>;  # Name1 can also be Name 2 or Name3 for second or third player
chomp $name1;
```

Comment: You could try using a [loop statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) of some sort, and saving each player name into some sort of variable or array. :)

Comment: This might be a good place to start : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html

Comment: @summea That's what I was thinking. I'll see the link kjprice provided.

Answer (score 2):

[Use a loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) and you can store the names in an array:

```
my @names;
for (1 .. $num) {
    print "Please enter your name\n";
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
    push @names, $name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This summed it up pretty quickly.